# HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ClearAuthenticationCache() throw 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: c#, cookies, win-universal-app, httpclient

I create an simple uwp app. The sdk version is Universal Windows 10.0.14332.0. The app does nothing, only call the function "HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ClearAuthenticationCache()". But when I call the "HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ClearAuthenticationCache()", an exception throwed:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   App2.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter' to type 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.IHttpBaseProtocolFilter4'.

How can I use "HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ClearAuthenticationCache()"?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.clearauthenticationcache.aspx), the ClearAuthenticationCache method is introduced in Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, version 3 and is available in OS version 10.0.14295.0 and later.

It means that the Windows.Web.Http.Filters.IHttpBaseProtocolFilter4 is not available in older version and you recieve an `InvalidCastException`.

So if you are targetting an older version as minimum, you need to [check if the API is available](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/) before calling the method:

```
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
 ...
 ...
if(ApiInformation.IsMethodPresent("Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ClearAuthenticationCache"))
{
    // Call the method here
}
```