# Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter' to type 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.IHttpBaseProtocolFilter3'

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, httpclient, windows-10-universal, dotnet-httpclient

I'm building a universal app for Windows 10 and mobile. 
I have this peace of code that work in Desktop and tablet:

```
 using (var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter())
            {
                filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;
                filter.AllowUI = false;
```

But when deployed to the emulator it throws the exception:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter' to type 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.IHttpBaseProtocolFilter3'.
```

in the line:

```
filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;
```

Any ideas what is happening here?

Regards.

Comment: What line in your code throws the exception? The constructor?

Comment: filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;

Comment: This should be an Api Contract version issue. The [CookieUsageBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.cookieusagebehavior) property is available in 10.0.10586.0 and above. See my answer to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200801/httpbaseprotocolfilter-clearauthenticationcache-throw-system-invalidcastexcep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was similar to what Mehrzad , just had to add this to make it work

```
 if (ApiInformation.IsPropertyPresent("Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter", "CookieUsageBehavior"))
        {
            filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;
        }
```

Thanks!